# Rust: Modifying to an object contained in a Vec from another object of the same Vec

Tags: object, rust, mutation

I have a `Vec<dyn MyObj>` and the first implementation of `MyObj` contained in the `Vec` can contains something that refers to a second implementation of `MyObj` contained in the same `Vec`.
I'd like that the first implementation can mutate the second implementation.

Here is my first idea:

```rust
use std::{rc::{Rc, Weak}, cell::RefCell};

trait MyObj {
    fn f(&mut self);
}

type CRef = Weak<RefCell<Container>>;

struct Container {
    list: Vec<Box<dyn MyObj>>,
    this: CRef,
}

impl Container {
    fn new() -> Rc<RefCell<Self>> {
        let res = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Self {
            list: vec![],
            this: Weak::new(),
        }));

        {
            let this = Rc::downgrade(&res);
            let mut ref_on_res = res.borrow_mut();

            ref_on_res.this = this;
        }

        res
    }

    fn register(&mut self, v: impl MyObj + 'static) -> ObjRef {
        let index = self.list.len();

        self.list.push(Box::new(v));

        ObjRef::new(self.this.clone(), index)
    }

    fn get(&mut self, index: usize) -> &mut (dyn MyObj + 'static) {
        let elt = &mut self.list[index];

        Box::as_mut(elt)
    }
}

struct ObjRef {
    c: CRef,
    i: usize,
}

impl ObjRef {
    fn new(c: CRef, i: usize) -> Self {
        Self { c, i }
    }
}

impl MyObj for ObjRef {
    fn f(&mut self) {
        let i = self.i;

        self.c.upgrade().map(|c| c.borrow_mut().get(i).f());
    }
}

struct A {
    r: ObjRef,
}

// First implementation
impl A {
    fn new(r: ObjRef) -> A {
        A { r }
    }
}

impl MyObj for A {
    fn f(&mut self) {
        self.r.f();
    }
}

// Second implementation
struct B(usize);

impl MyObj for B {
    fn f(&mut self) {
        self.0 += 1;
        println!("B({})", self.0);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let c = Container::new();
    let mut r = {
        let b = c.borrow_mut().register(B(100));

        c.borrow_mut().register(A::new(b))
    };

    r.f(); // -> Panic: already borrowed: BorrowMutError
}
```

Obviously, it panics and i understand why but i have no idea to fix this problem.

Have you any idea to do this kind of modification ?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't compile, can you upload a working example?

Comment: @Coder-256, that done.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to store data and references to the data in the same `Container`?

Comment: @L.F. container just store data (`Vec<Box<dyn MyObj>>`), there is no reference in container.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context? What is your code supposed to do? Not in terms of arrays, trait objects, cells, etc., I mean what action are you trying to do?

Comment: @Coder-256, the goal is the modification of an object contained in a Vec from another object of the same Vec, this done at line 61.  I try to do what is in function main. This code must work. There is no context, only this code. This is just an experience without context, this line 61 is the goal of this experience.

Comment: I suppose the `A` is a reference to the `B`?  Also, what you are trying to do is not generally possible in Rust (esp. without `unsafe`), and I highly suspect there is an XY problem going on.

Comment: @L.F. `A` is not a reference to the `B`, but `A` contains a reference to the `B`. Indeed, i hope that is possible with Rust safe code with a little soluce. If a `Box<dyn MyObj>` can outlive the Container, the `&mut` on the Container (with the `borrow_mut` in the `f` method of the `ObjRef`) could be dropped. But i don't know to do that without the needing of lifetime specifiers in the declaration of the Container.

Comment: What I meant is, there's a ton of complicated code but I still have absolutely no idea what that code *does*. But more importantly, I was strongly trying to hint the same thing as @L.F., this is almost certainly an XY problem: I suspect that the whole file might be the wrong approach, thus it doesn't make sense to answer your specific question. Could you explain the bigger picture?

Comment: @Coder-256, as i said to @L.F., the code does nothing, this is just an experience, a Proof Of Concept. This must just work. The goal of P.OC. is at line 61: modification another element of the same `Vec` (as said in the title of this article).

Comment: Ok. Are you just asking how to get a mutable reference to two separate elements in a `Vec` at the same time? You could just use `split_first_mut()`/`split_at_mut()` or similar. Or try to pattern match (e.g. `if let [head, tail @ ..] = self.vec`).